# How to solve the INVALID NOTEBOOK (The Notebook Does Not Appear to Be Valid JSON) error on GitHub?

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

All of my .ipynb files on GitHub have the same error message and will not load.

[image]

I am wondering how I can fix this problem. I have updated my Jupyter notebook, but it still shows this error. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at the files ("Code" tab)?  They are certainly supposed to be JSON.  Perhaps you should show us the first few lines of one of them.

Comment: @TimRoberts  Thank you for your response. How can I find the files ("code" tab)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tim is telling you to click on the 'Code' button that is to the right of the 'Preview' button in your screenshot. Find a good `.ipynb` file that has some content and then compare it to your 'problematic' file's code.  NOTE: If these are super old `.ipynb` files there probably isn't a real problem but the newer GitHub preview can fail with the older format. And the trick is to open the old file in newer Jupyter and resave. Also, so you know, the Jupyter offered [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) has better features than the GitHub preview. You can just put the URL of it at GitHub and see it.

Comment: <continued> **Short answer is there is probably nothing wrong.**  But you aren't providing enough information for use to tell you what is going on exactly. You should try nbviewer, especially given your are having issues. GitHub's preview isn't meant as more than a preview for coders. Point nbviewer at your notebooks and share the URL with people because it has less extra cruft than the preview at GitHub and supports more features. If you look at the URL nbviewer uses, you can see the pattern of how to point it at your GitHub URLs without needing to use the form to make the URLs.

Comment: @TimRoberts , I could not solve the problem,  here you can find a few lines of one of the Python files, hope you can help me!
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Jupyter Notebook</title>
    <link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/base/images/favicon-notebook.ico?v=eb02bb6f6435d048eba1bf1bd3b3621f8c14f26518dbadd8efd4ee6ee2721caf2367bc0cbc27d2ee2c35bc3b035aad07c6d625422b9445bf301897f493d0edc5">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/components/jquery-ui/dist/themes/smoothness/

Comment: That's not Python code, nor it is an ipynb file.  That is HTML.

Comment: @TimRoberts  Thank you, I solved that problem. I have to download the file as 'notbook.ipynb' on Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing outputs for all the cells in the notebook, I was using jupyter notebook in vscode and clearing output for all the cells worked for me